# List items won't fit correctly (leaves blank space on side)

Tags: css

Any ideas how it could be fixed?
Why list items are not fitting in line (no more than 3). Even if there is enough space to fit one more, it just leaves blank space instead. 
Code snippets:

```
<ul> . 
<li>Some product </li>
<li>Some product </li>
<li>Some product </li>
<li>Some product </li> <- This one should still fit the screen, but 
jumps to next line
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
display: inline-block !important;
margin: 2%!important;
border: 5px solid white;
background: white;
border-radius: 15px;
float: left;
width: 21% !important;
font-size: 1rem;
}

ul{
font-size: 0;
text-align: justify;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: You wanna post the CSS / HTML in question for us to look at?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: True, will keep that in mind, sorry for a bad post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#left-area ul.products {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

You have a lot of `!important` rules, so you may need to use `!important` to override those styles. For future reference, you shouldn't post a live URL, but instead create a static example as your website is likely to change overtime and if somebody else has this issue they will likely end up here without a solution.

Comment: upvoted for the comment "For future reference you shouldn't post a live URL but instead create a static example as your website is likely to change overtime and if somebody else has this issue they will likely end up here without a solution."

Comment: Good point with this advice, thank you, will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @ArūnasKiršis If the answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark icon to the left of it, to mark it as accepted and to indicate to others that it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

if you remove this from the CSS, you get all four boxes in a row:

```
@media (min-width: 981px)
    .et_full_width_page.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(4n+1), .et_left_sidebar.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(3n+1), .et_right_sidebar.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```